# How do I increment a value in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, reference

I have a nested dictionary & when I increment the value it assigns the reference every time.

```
sample_dict = {0:{'item': None},
               1:{'item': None}}
 
value = 1

for i in range(len(sample_dict)):
     sample_dict[i]['item'] = value
     value += 1
```

The output shows the value 2 for both not 1 then 2. It's using a reference to value. How do I stop that?

```
sample_dict = {0:{'item': 2},
               1:{'item': 2}}
```

Comment: It works fine on my machine. It produces the expected output.

Comment: To clarify, it also worked correctly on my machine, but I needed to add the missing `}`.

Comment: Please post the actual code that shows how `sample_dict` is initialized. `sample_dict` is more than likely initialized with a loop that keeps reusing the same sub-dict, unlike the dict literal included in your question.

Comment: Did you do `d = {'item': None}` followed by `sample_dict = {0: d, 1: d}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to run it correct.

```
    sample_dict = {
                0:{'item': None},
                1:{'item': None}
              }
 
value = 1

length = len(sample_dict)
for i in range(0, length):
     sample_dict[i]['item'] = value
     value += 1
     
print(sample_dict)
```

output:

```
{0: {'item': 1}, 1: {'item': 2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something as easy as this should work.

```
count = 0
for i in range(len(sample_dict)):
    sample_dict[count]['item'] = count +1
    count +=1
```

output

```
{0: {'item': 1}, 1: {'item': 2}}
```